# why lubuntu upgrade compile so many locales

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, language-support, locale

recently I upgraded my Lubuntu with apt-get upgrade, and I notice that "setting up locales" process takes quite long because it generates quite many locales for languages that's not used in the system.
In my /etc/locale conf:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

in my /etc/locale.gen:

```
many language code here, but all is commented save for
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

this is the snippets in the upgrade process :

```
Setting up locales (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  de_AT.UTF-8... done
  de_BE.UTF-8... done
  de_CH.UTF-8... done
  de_DE.UTF-8... done
  de_IT.UTF-8... done
  de_LI.UTF-8... done
  de_LU.UTF-8... done
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  ....
```

current version after upgrade

```
 ~  lsb_release -a                                                                     ✔ 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I would like to know why this happen, and if there is a way to omit this process for future upgrades, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to:

1. run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`
2. specify minimal set of needed locales (select by <kbd>Space</kbd>)
3. confirm locale rebuild (by <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the `<OK>` CLI "button")

Comment: Hi, I have selected 4 locales via the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` menu and it generated the `/etc/locale.gen` with 4 lines but still it generated 25 locales, why ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the files in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d`. There should be a file for every enabled locale (i.e. `en` and `de`). Edit the files as root user and remove all unwanted locales. Then re-run `locale-gen` as root.